# Importing rigify 2.79 rigs into 2.80

Tags: rigify

When trying to import a rigify rigged character from 2.79 to 2.80, the shapes disappear. Currently, the only way I know to retrieve them, is to go through the outliner, bone by bone and turn on wireframe. Has anyone found a better way to do this? Who would I contact in development to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

select all the bones shapes go in to mode edit-mode and go back to object-mode you will see...tell if it work